# solr is not able to create collection1

Tags: tomcat, solr

I was facing disk space issue. when i checked the issue there was deleted files of about 210GB's. so to clear that i restarted the tomcat process. but after restarting the tomcat. solr is not able to create collection1. below are the logs.

```
    SEVERE: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: java.io.IOException: No space left on device
        at org.apache.solr.update.TransactionLog.finish(TransactionLog.java:528)
        at org.apache.solr.update.UpdateLog.finish(UpdateLog.java:737)
        at org.apache.solr.update.processor.RunUpdateProcessor.finish(RunUpdateProcessorFactory.java:107)
        at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.finish(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:1042)
        at org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor.finish(LogUpdateProcessorFactory.java:179)
        at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.finish(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:76)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:83)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:129)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1699)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:455)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:276)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:947)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: No space left on device
        at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.writeMar 20, 2017 12:37:58 AM org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor finish
INFO: [collection1] webapp=/screener_common_solr path=/update/advance params={wt=javabin&version=2} {add=[0510a5ab-b1e8-408a-a478-a9c0ef98621d_F000000GE6 (1562365948936060928), 2262e3b5-8f49-49c2-9a39-5099fc3b1435_F000000GE6 (1562365948947595266), 0510a5ab-b1e8-408a-a478-a9c0ef98621d_F000000GDU (1562365948958081024), 2262e3b5-8f49-49c2-9a39-5099fc3b1435_F000000GDU (1562365948976955395), 0510a5ab-b1e8-408a-a478-a9c0ef98621d_F00000WGIS (1562365948993732608), 2262e3b5-8f49-49c2-9a39-5099fc3b1435_F00000WGIS (1562365948995829760), 0510a5ab-b1e8-408a-a478-a9c0ef98621d_F000000GE7 (1562365949000024064), 2262e3b5-8f49-49c2-9a39-5099fc3b1435_F000000GE7 (1562365949004218369), 0510a5ab-b1e8-408a-a478-a9c0ef98621d_F00000WGIT (1562365949010509824), 2262e3b5-8f49-49c2-9a39-5099fc3b1435_F00000WGIT (1562365949020995590), ... (53 adds)]} 0 651
Mar 20, 2017 12:37:58 AM org.apache.solr.common.SolrException log
SEVERE: java.io.IOException: No space left on device
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.writeBytes(Native Method)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.write(RandomAccessFile.java:499)
        at org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory$FSIndexOutput.flushBuffer(FSDirectory.java:524)
        at org.apache.lucene.store.BufferedIndexOutput.flushBuffer(BufferedIndexOutput.java:99)
        at org.apache.lucene.store.BufferedIndexOutput.flush(BufferedIndexOutput.java:88)
        at org.apache.lucene.store.BufferedIndexOutput.writeByte(BufferedIndexOutput.java:36)
        at org.apache.lucene.store.DataOutput.writeInt(DataOutput.java:71)
        at org.apache.lucene.store.DataOutput.writeLong(DataOutput.java:205)
        at org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene40.Lucene40StoredFieldsWriter.writeField(Lucene40StoredFieldsWriter.java:189)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.StoredFieldsConsumer.finishDocument(StoredFieldsConsumer.java:120)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.DocFieldProcessor.finishDocument(DocFieldProcessor.java:325)
at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriterPerThread.updateDocument(DocumentsWriterPerThread.java:262)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter.updateDocument(DocumentsWriter.java:373)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.updateDocument(IndexWriter.java:1445)
        at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.addDoc(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:210)
        at org.apache.solr.update.processor.RunUpdateProcessor.processAdd(RunUpdateProcessorFactory.java:61)
        at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:51)
        at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.doLocalAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:432)
        at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.versionAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:557)
        at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.processAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:325)
        at org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor.processAdd(LogUpdateProcessorFactory.java:100)
        at com.morningstar.productservices.search.screener.slolr.plugin.update.ScreenerAdvanceUpdateProcessorFactory$ScreenerAdvanceUpdateProcessor.processAdd(ScreenerAdvanceUpdateProcessorFactory.java:228)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.XMLLoader.processUpdate(XMLLoader.java:230)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.XMLLoader.load(XMLLoader.java:157)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.UpdateRequestHandler$1.load(UpdateRequestHandler.java:92)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:74)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:129)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1699)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:455)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:276)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:947)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

I checked the disk usage. now its showing 21% utilization. I tried to restart the solr again but now facing below issue.

```
Mar 20, 2017 11:34:21 PM org.apache.solr.common.SolrException log
SEVERE: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:179)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:129)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1699)
        at org.apache.solr.core.QuerySenderListener.newSearcher(QuerySenderListener.java:63)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore$5.call(SolrCore.java:1479)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

SEVERE: Unable to create core: collection1
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error Instantiating Update Handler, solr.DirectUpdateHandler2 failed to instantiate org.apache.solr.update.UpdateHandler
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:721)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:566)
        at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:850)
        at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.load(CoreContainer.java:534)
        at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.load(CoreContainer.java:356)
        at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$Initializer.initialize(CoreContainer.java:308)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.init(SolrDispatchFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:281)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:262)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4746)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5399)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:657)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1637)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: This error is triggered as there is no space left in the directory which contains the solr Home folder.If the directory is full and you are unable to allocate more space, please change the location of your home directory to somewhere where there is space available.

Answer (score 0):

The issue got resolved. due to the low disk space while indexing index data and transaction log was corrupted. so i deleted the index and tlog folder in solr, then restarted the solr service. after restarting there is no error. I need to reindex data again.